# Calling methods, java equation

Tags: java, methods

Can anyone help me to finish my java code.
So I have to write a program that calls a method then I need to use the following equation: f(x)=x<sup>2</sup>-16.

The output should be: 
And be print just once.

```
    X   F(x)
    1   -15 
    2   -12 
    3   -7 
    4    0 
    .    .
    .    .
    .    .
    10   84
```

I tried but the output is wrong. How can I fix it?
Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Lab12 {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
            f(i);
        }
    }

    public static void f(int num) {
        int result;
        result = num * num - 16;
        {
            System.out.println("X"+ "    " + "f(x)");
            for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
                System.out.println(result + "    "+num);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a loop inside your function which you don't appear to need. I would remove it.  I would also make `f` a function.

How about

```
public static int f(int x) {
    return x * x - 16;
}

public static void main(String[]args) {
    System.out.println("X\tf(x)");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + "\t" + f(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: @Joseph what do you mean by "does not".  Can you say how it differs from what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class YourFixedExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("X\tF(X)");
    for(int x = 0; x <= 10; ++x)
      System.out.println(x + "\t" + f(x));
  }
  static int f(int x) {
    return x*x - 16;
  }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, I got as output:
X       F(x)
-15    1
-15    1
-15    1
-15    1
-15    1
-15    1
-15    1
-15    1
-15    1
-15    1
X       F(x)
-12    2
-12    2
-12    2
-12    2
-12    2
-12    2
-12    2
-12    2
-12    2
-12    2
and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..  `printf` is a great way to format output http://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
    System.out.printf("%-15s %15s %n", "X", "f(x)");
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
        f(i);
    }
}

public static void f(int num) {
    int result = num * num - 16;
    System.out.printf( "%-15s %15s %n", result, num);
}
```

This is the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i + " " + solveMath(i));
    }
}          

public static int solveMath(int i)
{
    return i * i - 16;  
}
```